# Column value in Json Formatting code Sharepoint

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have a column (Review and Approval) which shows a button if the value is Start Workflow, and clicking it opens a flow in Power Automate. In the example below the ID of the power Automate Flow is 0123456789 (See below: Json code column Review and approval:) .

I need to have the result of a choice column instead of 0123456789. See below what I've tried (Idea I tried:).
I added a column Approval_Flow_ID, and replaced 01234567879 with [$Approval_Flow_ID], but the button doesn't show.
Any Idea's? THANXX

Json code column Review and approval:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"customRowAction": {
"action": "executeFlow",
"actionParams": "{\"id\": \"01234567890"}"
},
"style": {
"background-color": "#008082",
"color": "white",
"border-radius": "0 15px",
"visibility": "=if((@currentField == 'Start Workflow'),'visible','hidden')"
}
}
```

Idea I tried:

```
Json code column Review and approval:
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"customRowAction": {
"action": "executeFlow",
"actionParams": "{\"id\": \"[$Approval_Flow_ID]"}"
},
"style": {
"background-color": "#008082",
"color": "white",
"border-radius": "0 15px",
"visibility": "=if((@currentField == 'Start Workflow'),'visible','hidden')"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, it works normally on my end:
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
  "action": "executeFlow",
  "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"[$Flow_ID]\"}"
},
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#008082",
    "color": "white",
    "border-radius": "0 15px",
    "visibility": "=if((@currentField == 'Start Workflow'), 'visible', 'hidden')"
}
}
```

Check below:

1. I found that you lost " \ " here: `"actionParams": "{\"id\": \"[$Approval_Flow_ID]"}"`. It should be `"actionParams": "{\"id\": \"[$Approval_Flow_ID]\"}"`
2. Make sure you used the internal name of the choice column. Go to List settings > Columns > Click the choice column > Find it at the end of the URL.
   [image]

Comment: I had the last backslash in the choice column, and changed that.
The column name is indeed the internal name.

If I click the button, it can't find the flow, and the flow screen on the right hangs.
Same behavior of I click on the button for a file that has not selected the choice column value.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get the answer from  Allen to work.
Changing the actionParams to the following worked for me:

```
"actionParams": "='{\"id\":\"' + [$Approval_Flow_ID] + '\"}'"
```